# How to solve this integral: $\int_{-1}^{1} x^k (1-x^2)^{(n/2)-2} \, dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, gamma-function, hypergeometric-function

> How to solve this integral **step by step**:
>   $$\int_{-1}^{1} (x^k) (1-x^2)^{(n/2)-2}dx=??? $$

In my text book, it shows the result like below:

$$\int_{-1}^{1} (x^k) (1-x^2)^{(n/2)-2}dx= \frac{(x^{(1+k)} ~_2F_1((1+k)/2, ~2-n/2, ~(3+k)/2, ~x^2))}{(1+k)} ; for  ~x=-1~to~1~$$

$$=\frac{((1+(-1)^k) ~\Gamma(\frac{1+k}{2}) ~\Gamma(\frac{-1+n}{2})}{2Γ( \frac{1}{2}(-1+k+n))}$$

Note: $~_2F_1((1+k)/2, ~2-n/2, ~(3+k)/2, ~x^2)$ is a hypergeometric function, is there a simple way to find and solve that integral?

Thanks in advanced

Comment: If $k$ is odd, you can make a substitution ($t=x^2$) and write it as a $\beta$ function.

Comment: You mean "if $k$ is even", don't you? If $k$ is odd, the integrand is odd, hence the integral is $0$.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan I do not understand about what you mention. any way can you show me how to prove it step by step?

Comment: @DanielFischer we do not yet talking about k is even or odd (please skip it first, because i know how to work it after). my problem is how to show the integral become hypergeometric answer and after that become gamma function?

Comment: @valerie My comment replied to Prahlad's.

Comment: @valerie : you don't solve definite integrals, you evaluate them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following Daniel's comments:

**Case $1$ --- $\;k\ge 0\;$ is odd:** In this case, the integrand $\;x^k(1-x^2)^{\frac n2-2}\;$ is an odd continuous function in a symmetric interval and thus the integral equals zero.

**Case $2$ --- $\;k=2m\ge 0\;$ is even:** in this case our integral equals twice the integral over half the interval and we can substitute:

$$u:=x^2\implies dx=\frac{du}{2\sqrt u}\implies$$

$$\int\limits_{-1}^1 x^k(1-x^2)^{\frac n2-2}dx=2\int\limits_0^2 (x^2)^m(1-x^2)^{\frac n2-2}dx=$$

$$2\int\limits_0^1u^m(1-u)^{\frac n2-2}\frac{du}{2u^{1/2}}=\int\limits_0^1u^{m-1/2}(1-u)^{\frac n2-2}du=:B\left(\frac{k+1}2\,,\,\color{}{\frac{n-2}2}\right)$$

and, for example using the relation between gamma and beta functions, we have

$$B\left(\frac{k+1}2\,,\,\frac{n-2}2\right)=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{k+1}2\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{n-2}2\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{k+n-1}2\right)}$$

Comment: thanks for the answer, I like your solving. But any way why the end of your result is different?

Comment: Well, for odd $\;k\;$ we both get the same: zero, and for even $\;k\;$ we get the same...after I correct the typo I did when writing my answer. Look at it now, I'll write it in red.

Comment: Hmmm...I'm not sure from where that $\;-1\;$ in the argument of the denominator's Gamma in your answer comes from...

Comment: I got the answer..your answer is really CORRECT. but you have made miss type in $B( \frac{k+1}{2}, \frac{n-1}{2})$ should be $B( \frac{k+1}{2}, \frac{n-2}{2})$

Comment: Ah, right there, @valerie! Thanks. The problem is that anything beyond $\;1+1=2\;$ is way too hard for me, and graduate school didn't help with this...:)

Answer (score 3):

Let $x = \sin(t)$. We then have $dx = \cos(t)dt$. Hence,
$$I(k,n) = \int_{-1}^1 x^k(1-x^2)^{n/2-2}dx = \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \sin^k(t) (\cos^{2}(t))^{n/2-2} \cos(t)dt$$
Hence, we get that
$$I(k,n) = \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \sin^k(t) \cos^{n-3}(t)dt$$
For $k$ odd, we get that $I(k,n) = 0$. For even $k$, we get that
$$I(k,n) = 2 \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin^{k}(t) \cos^{n-3}(t)dt = \beta\left(\dfrac{k+1}2, \dfrac{n-2}2\right)$$